Sizeof operator doesn't work properly after insertion an element
I am trying to make a program in C to insert an element to an array.
I used sizeof operator to determine array's total number of elements but after   inserting an element and reusing sizeof operator it seems that it doesn't work properly (It gives me the same result without incrementing).
Thanks in advance.
// Exercise N9 - Code Win
// Arrays.
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    int user_input;
    
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    
    
    printf("Hey User !\n");
    printf("Enter an element :\n");
    scanf("%i",&user_input);
    
    int elements_number;
    elements_number = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    
    int new_element_index;
    new_element_index = elements_number;  // Because computer starts from zero.
    
    array[new_element_index] = user_input;
    
    int elements_number_after;
    elements_number_after = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ",array[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("%i\n",elements_number);
    printf("%i\n",elements_number_after);
    
    return 0;
}



Why do you expect elements_number to be different from elements_number_after? They perform exactly the same calculation.

Your array is always the same size. That is, it has the size you have allocated to it. The fact that you are changing it's content does not change the size. And no, you can't write past the last element, so your array[new_element_index] = user_input; is wrong.

for (i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) is incorrect anyway. The array only has 5 elements. Instead of the hard coded 6 you should have used the length elements_number you already calculated.

Thanks to everyone, I comprehended it well.

OT: Historically, sizeof has always been a compile-time operator, NOT a runtime function... The value it represents (represented) has been a compile-time constant and does not vary during execution... See this That's why sizeof arr works. sizeof( arr ) is valid, but can be misleading to beginners.

Sidenote: a good habit to develop is checking the return value from scanf calls. How do you know this succeeded:  scanf("%i",&user_input);? After this line, user_input could still be uninitialized with an indeterminate value. If you actually used user_input that might come back to bite you. Usually in the least predictable and most annoying way.

int elements_number;
elements_number = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

The above returns 5 (which should have been stored in a size_t). Continuing onwards:
int new_element_index;
new_element_index = elements_number;  // Because computer starts from zero.
    
array[new_element_index] = user_input;

The last line invokes undefined behavior because the value of new_element_index was 5, and array[5] accesses out of bounds memory. Arrays in C are fixed-size and do not automatically grow. You can't allocate space for 5 integers and then fit 6 into them.
The second calculation returns 5 because attempting to write to one past the size of the array doesn't actually change the size of the array. It is going to remain 5 no matter what you do.
What you're looking for is dynamic memory allocation, namely malloc() and realloc().

It might be worth noting that sizeof() won't be useful with the dynamically allocated arrays managed with malloc() and realloc() and free().  With dynamically allocated arrays, the OP will have to track the array size in their code.

In C, arrays do not grow; nor do they shrink either.
So (ignoring the Undefined Behaviour in your code), if your calculation tells you that the array size is the same after you did ... anything ... then it is actually correct.
To be precise, this is about actual arrays; anything with malloc() is out of scope here.
